# convert mongoose schema to django model

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-rest-framework, mongoose-schema

I have below javascript schema

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  timestamp: Number,
  coords: {
    latitude: Number,
    longitude: Number,
    altitude: Number,
    accuracy: Number,
    heading: Number,
    speed: Number
  }
});
const trackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  locations: [pointSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Track', trackSchema);
```

I'm trying to convert above file to Django models. wondering how to write that `locations: [pointSchema]` and `const pointSchema` in my models.py.

Is it possible to convert that ?

this is how express server saves the data. I want to achieve same

```
router.post('/tracks', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, locations } = req.body;

  if (!name || !locations) {
    return res
      .status(422)
      .send({ error: 'You must provide a name and locations' });
  }

  try {
    const track = new Track({ name, locations, userId: req.user._id });
    await track.save();
    res.send(track);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be using a `Many-to-one relationship` depicted as a `ForeignKey` for the first part. Taking the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) as a basis here, it would look like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class Coords(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(...)
    longitude = models.FloatField(...)
    ...

class PointSchema(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(...)
    coords = models.ForeignKey(Coords, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And for `trackSchema`, we use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Short excerpt:

```py
class TrackSchema(models.Model):
    ...
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(PointSchema)
    ...
```

Comment: @dackx but for that I have to expose "Coords" and "PointSchema" from my api and add them first. I need to be able to save them from  "TrackSchema" it self.

Comment: You can get that full json like you do in JS and extract the values for your TrackSchema.